# Security Testing a Website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

I am currently working on a school assignment which requires us to perform security testing on a website created by one of our peers. The website is created using ASP.Net 3.5/4 and an MS-SQL database.

The website's main features are:

- Registration & Login using Roles
- Uploading documents
- Sharing of uploaded documents
- Leaving comments on shared documents

I already have started testing the website using:

- XSS in the Register, Login and Leave Comment Sections
- SQL Injection in the Register and Login pages
- Upload of executables, with a different extension (I have changed an executable file to `.doc` to test whether the system is checking the extension of the file or the actual contents)

These tests have been carried out manually and I have access to the source code!

Can you suggest any other tests I might want to carry out?

Cheers

Comment: How did you carry out the tests? did you use any automated vulnerability testing tools? or just manually?

Comment: Manually, I have the source code but I should start first with "black-box" testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good resource for things to lock-down would be [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) - I linked to their "top ten" items as I have followed it myself for locking down apps and found it really helpful.

Drilling down into any item on their top ten list will discuss how to recognize a particular vulnerability and suggest how to remove the vulnerability. All code-agnostic stuff, high-level descriptions so it can be applied to any project be it .Net, Ruby, PHP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check for Local File Inclusion and Remote File Inclusion vulnerabilities as well.

You can also check the login system: If the website lets you login (and you have an account or can make one), login and check to see how the login code works (i.e. check your cookies to see if they are PHP sessions [secure] or some other method [usually not secure]).  If you find a vulnerability in the login system, you could elevate your privileges from regular user to admin.

Also, "Upload of executables, with a different extension."  Could you clarify that for me?

The best thing to do is to use your imagination.

Comment: I have renamed a file which is an executable to .doc to check whether the file upload mechanism is actually checking the file data or simply the extension! Thanks

Comment: The upload mechanism will rarely check the actual file data.  A better test would be to see if you can upload and run any server-side code.  For example, create an ASP file that prints the version (or something else simple) and upload different extensions to see if the upload script creator forgot a certain extension (i.e. file.asp, file.aspx, etc).  You will have to google around for more extensions because I'm not an IIS/ASP guy.  Also, check for third party plugins.  I believe perl (and probably others) can be installed on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use Cat.NET's engine (which is a free Microsoft provide security focused static analysis tool).

I have been working on making Cat.NET easier and faster to use inside VisualStudio and here is a pretty cool PoC of how it in action: [Real-time Vulnerability Creation Feedback inside VisualStudio (with Greens and Reds)](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/real-time-vulnerability-creation.html)

If you are interested in Cat.NET you can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19968